# where can I find the project to build DirectShow BaseClasses?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, directshow

I am working on a software product that goes waaaay back. Part of our source code is a project that builds baseclasses. This is supposedly a project that ships with the Windows SDK and is used for developing apps that reference DirectShow.

Unfortunately the version we have checked in to our repository is out of date and issues many warnings when we build (all related to  `warning C4996: 'GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated`).

Personally, I cannot find any information about how to find the newest (or indeed any) version of this little nugget of Windows goodness. As recently as a few days ago Microsoft Learn published a tutorial about this very topic (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow-base-classes). But, it is essentially useless.

For example, if I click here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/using-the-directshow-base-classes it tells me:

> The base class library is provided as a SDK sample in the Microsoft
> Windows Software Development Kit (SDK)
> (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=62332). The exact location
> depends on the version of the SDK that you have installed, but the
> relative path is:
>
> `(SDK samples root)\DirectShow\BaseClasses`

I have Visual Studio 2022 installed and there is no such path in its directory tree, nor in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits. However, if I click on the link quoted, it sends me to a page that basically tells me that all I need to do to get the Windows SDK is download Visual Studio. Hmmmm....

Does anyone know how to get a contemporary version of the DirectShow base classes? Microsoft is not being very helpful on this point.

Comment: I'd have to look this up, but it might have come bundled with one of the older DirectX SDKs. I recall it being a one-off directory in either the Windows SDK of its time or the DirectX SDK bundle.

Comment: https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/tree/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow

Comment: Whenever you find documentation that's not (or no longer) useful, make sure to click the *"Feedback"* link (top right), select *"No"* (this page is not useful), and leave a comment. While I'm not convinced that doing that has any effect I know for a fact that *not* leaving feedback certainly won't.

Comment: Oh, I left feedback indicating that this was not useful. What is odd is that  dated December 15 of 2022 which is 6 days ago as of today. I would guess the MS does look at the feedback *eventually*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic Microsoft: Moving things around but failing to update references.

If you navigate to [DirectShow sample apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow-samples), you'll find the link to the new GitHub home under [Windows-classic-samples/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow), including the [baseclasses](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses) directory.

Since you are explicitly asking for a *"contemporary"* version of the DirectShow base classes, that's what the GitHub repository contains. They haven't been (to my knowledge) updated since. DirectShow is in maintenance mode, and Microsoft encourage clients to use more recent technologies instead (such as [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) or the Windows Runtime types under the [`Windows.Media.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture) namespace).

Comment: I guess this repo is indeed the newest version. I didn't do a compare on every file, but looking at dllentry.cpp is identical to the version that ships with the Windows 7 SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279. This contains the deprecated call to `GetVersionEx` which is what is giving me specific grief (compiler warnings and anxiety that it will return the wrong answer). It appears that Microsoft should drop the pretense that this is supported technology.

Comment: @dmedine `GetVersionEx` will return the wrong result. This is inconsequential, though; only the part that's correctly reported is used (`dwPlatformId`), with the potentially wrong version number ignored. That value is used to determine whether the system provides the wide-character version of `LoadStringW` (all versions of Windows NT do). If that is something you'd wish to avoid, you can remove all code that accesses and populates `g_amPlatform`, and just call `LoadStringW` unconditionally in *videoctl.cpp*.

Answer (score 1):

For this reason I copied the directshow baseclasses and included them in the project, when I implemented GraphStudioNext. I didn't touch the project in a while but maybe this helps: https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/tree/master/baseclasses

PS: I just saw, Roman has a more updated version of the base classes: https://alax.info/blog/2157

Comment: This is hilarious: https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/blob/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/dllentry.cpp#L309-L322